# Asyncio performance with synchronous code

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio, uvloop

I create the following test to check performance with running synchronous code in async function.

In `return_random` function can be something like write log, dump or load json, validate in-out date, which call other functions... etc.

count_sync and count_async variables using for skip overhead for open and close event loop. just calculate time inside function.

This part of code just call synchronous function count times.

```
import timeit
from time import time
from random import random

count = 100
run_numbers = 100000

count_sync = 0

def return_random():
    return random()

def test():
    global count_sync
    start = time()
    for _ in range(count):
       return_random()
    count_sync += time() - start
    return

total_sunc = timeit.timeit('test()', globals=globals(), 
      number=run_numbers))
```

Same code but now `return_random` is asynchronous function:

```
import asyncio
import uvloop

asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(uvloop.EventLoopPolicy())

count_async = 0

async def return_random_async():
   return random()

async def test_async():
   global count_async
   start = time()
   for _ in range(count):
      await return_random_async()
   count_async += time() - start
   return

total_sunc = timeit.timeit('asyncio.run(test_async())', globals=globals(), number=run_numbers)
```

After running code with different numbers of call function and count of timeit running got following results:

```
RUNNING run_numbers: 1000. CALL FUNCTIONS count: 1000
total sync:  0.12023316
total Async: 0.48369559500000003
inside def sync  0.11995530128479004
inside def Async:0.24073457717895508

RUNNING run_numbers: 100000. CALL FUNCTIONS count: 100
total sync:   1.422697458
total Async: 25.452165134999998   (!!!)
inside def sync:  1.3965537548065186
inside def Async: 2.8397130966186523
```

All times run with synchronous function faster more than 2 times.

Is it means that running synchronous code better with not async function?
And preferably do not use a lot async functions ?

Comment: There is no surprise. Asynchronous needs context switch. Although it is much more lightweight than threads, it still costs a little bit.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use async functions only when you really need. Examples: asynchronous http libraries like `aiohttp`, asynchronous drivers like `motor_asyncio` for MongoDB, etc. In other cases it's better to run synchronous code with not async functions, because they have an overhead that you don't need to have.